# Aristotelian Syllogisms ... in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, logic, prototype

I've got a fun one for you - Aristotle and Javascript!

I'm in the middle of writing a blog post on the .prototype, .**proto** and inheritance in general, but rather than use foo and bar, I prefer the good ole' Aristotelian syllogism.

*All men are mortal,
Socrates is a man,
(therefore) Socrates is mortal*

(All *persons* are mortal, to be modern),
Put into the simplest of constructor functions, I see it looking like this:

```
function Person(){
this.mortality = true;
};
socrates = new Person();
socrates.mortality == true; //returns true, Socrates is mortal
```

I can see how you'd apply it to something like "no reptiles have fur, a snake is a reptile, therefore..." but what about "Some?"

How would this look in javascript, using inheritance/prototypes (i.e., not using a simple if/else or switch statement):

*No homework is enjoyable, 
Some reading is homework, 
(therefore) Some reading unenjoyable.*

More examples here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syllogism

Perhaps I could figure it out delving into boolean algebra, etc, but I really need an excuse to make my first Stack Overflow post!  Let me know what you guys think, thanks!

Comment: This guy thinks that the use of Socrates and references to Syllogisms has muddied the waters to the extent that it's not at all clear what you're asking.

Comment: So logically what you want is to have three possible outcomes: true, false, or some. For two possibilities, we generally use true and false, but could just as easily use 0 and 1.  For three values, you could use 0, 1, and 2.  0 is false, 1 is true, 2 is some (or whatever association makes the most sense for you.)  You can then from there set and compare the values.  I'm not much of a Javascript guy, but hopefully that gets you thinking programmatically with what you want to do.

Comment: I'm not sure how this relates to inheritance. You don't even show inheritance, you are just setting a Boolean property. *If* you wanted to express "some" with inheritance, then that would mean that some reading is homework and some isn't. However, you cannot really create such an conditional inheritance. Maybe you could use dynamic mixins.

Comment: The Man function could have been:
function Man(){
this.legs = 2;
}
socrates = new Man();
socrates.legs; // returns 2
But that's boring ... "All men are mortal" is a famous historical statement. In this case "mortality" is a Boolean value, and Socrates 'inherits' that value as true. (he is mortal) Boolean Algebra and symbolic logic from that era is what all our code was originally based on, and Boole (like all his contemporaries) grew up reading Aristotle. So yes, I think it is important and worthwhile to dig around in the archeology of our higher-level languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

+1 to the question for being interdisciplinary.

In general, I would associate "some" with the idea of instantiating a class (insofar as JavaScript has classes.) JavaScript is a bit clumsy when trying to model multiple inheritance (which would correspond to saying "Some A are B"), so one way to model sets is to use attributes instead, as is done in the following example with the `is_reading` attribute which models membership in the `Reading` set:

```
// No homework is enjoyable
function Homework(is_reading) {
    this.is_reading = is_reading;
    this.enjoyable = false; }

// Some reading is homework
var vogon_poetry = new Homework(true)

// Some reading is unenjoyable
vogon_poetry.is_reading && !vogon_poetry.enjoyable // true
```

Comment: I like your answer because it accounts for the case where a new Homework may NOT be reading, yet still be unenjoyable.  As below:
`code`
function Homework(is_reading) {
    this.is_reading = is_reading;
    this.enjoyable = false; }

// Some reading is homework
var vogon_poetry_documentary = new Homework(false)

// A non-reading homework, still unenjoyable. 
!vogon_poetry_documentary.enjoyable == true // returns true.
`code`
Aristotle and rest of the 'logicians' until the Renaissance were obsessed with the 'intersection of classes' - these kind of 'necessarily so' by definition inferences.

Answer (score 0):

```
function Candy() {}

function Airhead() {}
Airhead.prototype.chewy = true;

function Jawbreaker() {}
Jawbreaker.prototype.chewy = false;
```

Airheads are chewy. Some candy is Airheads; therefore, some candy is chewy.